# VueJS PWA: service worker nog working. Maybe due to .htaccess file?

Tags: apache, vue.js, vue-router, progressive-web-apps

I've build a `PWA` with `vue`. Everything is working fine in development and when I deploy to chrome webserver. Service worker is registrated and running. So far so good.

When I deploy to production, service worker isn't running due to the fact that the `scope` or `start_url` is not matching `manifest.json` (thats what google dev tools tells me).

I believe it's due to the fact that I'm running `vue-router` in history mode and have a `.htaccess` file running on production to rewrite rules as recommended [here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations).

I've also tested this to switch back to hash mode in `vue-router` and deploy to production again. Then service worker is working just fine.

To overcome this problem I've tried to set the scope in `manifest.json` and service worker to `index.html`:

```js
register(`${process.env.BASE_URL}service-worker.js`, {
    registrationOptions: { scope: 'index.html' },
    ready () {
      console.log(
        'App is being served from cache by a service worker.\n'
      )
    }
})
```

The same for `manifest.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "short_name": "myapp",
  "theme_color": "#4DBA87",
  "icons": [
    { "src": "./img/icons/android-chrome-192x192.png", "sizes": "192x192", "type": "image/png" },
    { "src": "./img/icons/android-chrome-512x512.png", "sizes": "512x512", "type": "image/png" },
    { "src": "./img/icons/android-chrome-maskable-192x192.png", "sizes": "192x192", "type": "image/png", "purpose": "maskable" },
    { "src": "./img/icons/android-chrome-maskable-512x512.png", "sizes": "512x512", "type": "image/png", "purpose": "maskable" }
  ],
  "start_url": "index.html",
  "scope": "index.html",
  "orientation": "portrait",
  "display": "standalone",
  "background_color": "#000000"
}
```

But still chrome gives me the message about scope being not in sync.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Have the same problem.. .htaccess gives a 403 error in the service worker. Did you resolve this?

Comment: @Jos Faber No. I switched back to hashmode in `vue-router`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to package.json config for pwa plugin:

```json
  "vue": {
    "pwa": {
      "workboxOptions": {
        "exclude": [
          ".htaccess"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

---

UPDATE:

This action excludes .htaccess file from SW cache.
So, your SW won't crash and won't attempt to download .htaccess file from server.

At least, I faced with same problem and found this StackOverflow topic without answer. So, I read Vue PWA doc and found this, working for me, way.

Comment: Please extend your answer a bit. What happens when this configuration is added and how does it solve the problem?

Comment: This solution works. What it basically does is excluding `.htaccess` files form cashing (causing the problem). I actually gained the same effect by deleting my `.htaccess` file completly from my project directory since I only need it on my production server..